# Calculating unit tangent vector for discrete points. Why is my answer slightly off?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I have a discretized curve represented by points containing 3 parameters (x,y,$\theta$). $\theta$ is the direction to the next point.

I want to calculate the unit tangent vector and its derivative for these points. I learned about this in Calculus III that the unit tangent vector is defined by:

$\hat{T}=\frac{\vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}$

I decided to perform some experimental calculations to make sure I had a good grasp of the problem and this is where I've run into a problem.

#### My Experiment

Take two adjacent points on the line which are an arbitrary distance apart. Say that point A has a $\theta$ value of $\pi/3$ and point B has a $\theta$ value of $\pi/6$. Then what is $||\Delta\hat{T}||$?

1) Find $\hat{T}$ for point A and point B...

$\hat{T}_A$ = (cos($\pi/3$), sin($\pi/3$))

$\hat{T}_B$ = (cos($\pi/6$), sin($\pi/6$))

2) Use the forward difference to find $\Delta\hat{T}$

$\hat{T}_B$ - $\hat{T}_A$ = (cos($\pi/6$), sin($\pi/6$)) - (cos($\pi/3$), sin($\pi/3$))

3) Take the magnitude

||(cos($\pi/6$) - (cos($\pi/3$), sin($\pi/6$) - sin($\pi/3$))|| = $\sqrt{-\sqrt{3}+2}$
= 517.638E-3

4) Compare with the magnitude of the difference in radians to check my result.

$||\pi/6 - \pi/3 || = \pi/6 = 523.5987E-3$

The answer is close, but it is not exact. I've tried with other angles and this seems to be the case. What am I misunderstanding?

Edit: It seems that for small differences in angle, I will get the same result, but with a large change, my result won't be the same. I am still interested to hear what someone might say about this.

Comment: Typo in the last line, its $\pi/6$

Comment: Right. Fixing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not well versed in discrete curves/objects...

But, from what I've read, you're computing two things that are supposed to be different. Let $\Delta\theta$ be the difference in angle between the tangent vectors. You have
\begin{align*}
\left\|\Delta\hat T\right\|^2
&=\left\| \hat T_B-\hat T_A \right\|^2
=\left\| \hat T_B \right\|^2 -2\left\| \hat T_B \right\|\left\| \hat T_A\right\|\cos\left(\Delta\theta\right)+\left\| \hat T_A \right\|^2
=2\big( 1-\cos\left(\Delta\theta\right) \big)\\
&= 2\left( \frac{\Delta\theta^2}2 -\frac{\Delta\theta^4}{24} +o\left(\Delta\theta^5\right) \right)\\
\left\|\Delta\hat T\right\|
&=\left\lvert\Delta\theta\right\rvert
\left( 1-\frac{\Delta\theta^2}{12}+o\left(\Delta\theta^3\right)\right)^{1/2}
=\left\lvert\Delta\theta\right\rvert\left( 1 -\frac{\Delta\theta^2}{24} +o\left(\Delta\theta^2\right) \right)
\end{align*}
To summarize (and assuming I didn't screw up the Taylor series expansion [? not certain of the English name for this thing]) when $\Delta\theta$ is close to $0$,
$$
\left\|\Delta\hat T\right\| \approx
\left\lvert\Delta\theta\right\rvert -\frac{\left\lvert\Delta\theta\right\rvert\Delta\theta^2}{24}
$$
So the smaller the value of $\Delta\theta$, the smaller the difference with
$\left\|\Delta\hat T\right\|$. But these two things are strictly different.

Comment: I follow your first two lines, but not the third line. i.e. I'm not sure how you've computed the square root like that. Could you explain the third line?

Comment: @Klik Third line is taking the square root of second line, and doing the expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$ for small values of $x$. Before doing the expansion, you can factor away $\frac{\Delta\theta^2}2$, which yields the absolute value in front.
If you still have trouble seeing the expansion, take $x=-\frac{\Delta\theta^2}{12}+o(\Delta\theta^3)$.

Comment: I believe this fully answers my question and I will mark it as the answer. For my benefit, could you please give me some keywords to read up on this type of polynomial expansion (not Taylor Series, but removing the square root). I'd like to familiarize myself.

Comment: @Klik Hmm... when I googled the English translation to the keyword it directed me to Taylor series, and checking the wikipedia page for it, they explain how to expand $(1+x)^\alpha$, precisely there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series
If you speak French I could tell you the French name though.

Comment: Perfect, that's a good place to start digging. Cheers!